# How to avoid unnecessary uglifying in GruntJS?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a grunt file with the following definition:

```
uglify: {
        build: {
                src: 'www/temp/application.js', // a concatenation of files via grunt-contrib-concat
                dest: 'www/temp/application.min.js'
        }
},
```

what I would really like to do is to recompute the final `application.min.js` only in case that `application.js` file was changed. More precisely, I want to add the condition:

```
# pseudocode

if (getFileContents(application.js) == getFileContents(previously.uglified.application.js)) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    // run uglifying on application.js
}
```

**Reason:**

- I deploy my project by git and uglifying is relatively slow (3+ seconds) and moreover, it is unnecessary since I don't change JS files often.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions:

You can create your own grunt task that will check files for last modify time using for example [fs.stat](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.stat) then run `uglify` task through [grunt.task.run](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run) with prepared options as argument.

Or you can build files object dynamically passing it through filter function:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  function filterChanged(files) {
    var mtime = '',
        stats;

    for (var dest in files) {
      stats = fs.statSync(files[dest]);

      try {
        mtime = fs.readFileSync(files[dest] + '.mtime', 'utf8');
      }
      catch (ex) {
        fs.writeFileSync(files[dest] + '.mtime', stats.mtime, 'utf8');
        return files;
      }

      if (stats.mtime == mtime || !mtime) {
        delete files[dest];
      }
      else {
        fs.writeFileSync(files[dest] + '.mtime', stats.mtime, 'utf8');
      }
    }

    return files;
  }

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      build: {
        files: filterChanged({
          'www/temp/application.min.js': 'www/temp/application.js'
        })
      }
    }
  });

};
```

This causes invoke of `filterChanged` function every time `uglify` task runs.

Comment: +1 for the documentation link to Node.js (I don't know the platform very well). Based on my question I'm rather looking for something like `fs.readFile`. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for +1. I've had a time and I've edited answer with actual working filter sample. It's based on .mtime files, which contains last modify time for your source file. Not the best, but working solution for your roblem.